# python parse http response (string)

Tags: python, http

I'm using python 2.7 and I want to parse string HTTP response fields which I already extracted from a text file. What would be the easiest way? I can parse requests by using the BaseHTTPServer but couldn't manage to find something for the responses.

The responses I have are pretty standard and in the following format

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, Jul  3 15:27:54 2014
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Connection: close
Content-Length: 626
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You might find this useful, keep in mind that [HTTPResponse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPResponse) wasn't designed to be "instantiated directly by user."

Also note that the content-length header in your response string may not be valid any more (it depends on how you've aquired these responses) this just means that the call to HTTPResponse.read() needs to have value larger than the content in order to get it all.

In python 2 it can be run this way.

```
from httplib import HTTPResponse
from StringIO import StringIO

http_response_str = """HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, Jul  3 15:27:54 2014
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Connection: close
Content-Length: 626"""

class FakeSocket():
    def __init__(self, response_str):
        self._file = StringIO(response_str)
    def makefile(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._file

source = FakeSocket(http_response_str)
response = HTTPResponse(source)
response.begin()
print "status:", response.status
print "single header:", response.getheader('Content-Type')
print "content:", response.read(len(http_response_str)) # the len here will give a 'big enough' value to read the whole content
```

In python 3, the `HTTPResponse` is imported from `http.client`, and the response to be parsed needs to be byte encoded. Depending on where the data is gotten from this may be done already or need to be called explicitly

```
from http.client import HTTPResponse
from io import BytesIO

http_response_str = """HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, Jul  3 15:27:54 2014
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Connection: close
Content-Length: 626

teststring"""

http_response_bytes = http_response_str.encode()

class FakeSocket():
    def __init__(self, response_bytes):
        self._file = BytesIO(response_bytes)
    def makefile(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._file

source = FakeSocket(http_response_bytes)
response = HTTPResponse(source)
response.begin()
print( "status:", response.status)
# status: 200
print( "single header:", response.getheader('Content-Type'))
# single header: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
print( "content:", response.read(len(http_response_str)))
# content: b'teststring'
```

Comment: This does really look like the trick I needed. I probably could work my way through by using regexes for my simple purposes but using HTTPResponse feels a lot more correct. Thanks very much.

Comment: As a follow up, tested and yes, this does what I want.

Comment: but what if there's a keep-alive connection? can we parse multiple headers/body using this solution? something like the example of this unanswered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786880/multiple-response-parsing-in-python?lq=1

Comment: How do i find, if response format was valid and parsing succeeded?

Comment: for python3 you can use `from http.client import HTTPResponse`

Comment: Has anyone made this work with Python3? I am getting `TypeError: decoding str is not supported`  at `File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")`

Comment: One of the most useful answer's I've seen on Stack!

Answer (score -8):

You might want to consider using python-requests.

Link: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Here is an example from http://dancallahan.info/journal/python-requests/

Considering your responses are compliant with HTTP RFC

Does this look like something you want to do?

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://example.test/'
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> response.status_code
200
>>> response.headers['content-type']
'text/html; charset=utf-8'
>>> response.content
u'Hello, world!'
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: How would you load a already existing response string into it?

Comment: This is an irrelevant answer. Question was about parsing an already existing full response string not making a request itself.