# Multiple response parsing in python

Tags: python, linux, hadoop, curl, webhdfs

I am using curl command to access hadoop(webhdfs) and for http response parsing i am using python.

But after firing curl command ,multiple responses are being returned.

```
curl -i  "http://host:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/hduser/pigtest?op=GETFILESTATUS"

HTTP/1.1 401 Authentication required
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 10:04:23 GMT
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 10:04:23 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 10:04:23 GMT
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 10:04:23 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: plain/text
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.hwx)

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 10:04:23 GMT
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 10:04:23 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 10:04:23 GMT
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 10:04:23 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.hwx)

{"FileStatus":{"accessTime":1452062206193,"blockSize":134217728,"childrenNum":0,"fileId":39295,"group":"hdfs","length":753,"modificationTime":1452062206392,"owner":"hduser","pathSuffix":"","permission":"644","replication":2,"storagePolicy":0,"type":"FILE"}}
```

How do i parse these multiple responses in python?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us how you get that responses input into Python ?

Comment: That's a broken response that isn't HTTP compliant.

Comment: @Saksow: Currently i a usiin above response in string to parse it. I referred this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728088/python-parse-http-response-string

Comment: Just to give more info, I am using --negotiate -u: option along with curl as i haver kerberos enabled cluster.