# How to decode a source code which is compressed with gzip in python

Tags: php, python, html, gzip, compression

I am trying to get the source code of a php web page with a proxy, but it is showing not printable characters. The output I got is as follows:

```
 "Date: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 10:29:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=jmqasueos33vqoe6dbm3iscvg0; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 577
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

�TMo�@�G����7�)P�H�H�DS��=U�=�U�]˻��_�Ycl�T�*�>��eg��
                                                          ����Z�
                                                                �V�N�f�:6�ԫ�IkZ77�A��nG�W��ɗ���RGY��Oc`-ο�ƜO��~?�V��$�
                            �l4�+���n�].W��TǇSx�/|�n��#���>��r����;�l����H��4��f�\  �SY�y��7��"
```

how to decode this code using python, i tried to use

```
decd=zlib.decompress(data, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

but is not giving the decoded data

The proxy which i am using is working fine for few other web applications. It showing non printable characters for some web applications, how to decode this?

As I am using proxy I dont want to use  get() and urlopen() or any other requests from python program.

Comment: How are you retrieving the URL? If you use the `requests` module the content will be automatically decompressed for you.

Comment: So you just want to know how to decompress the body of the HTTP response? What is the input? Is it the whole HTTP response, including headers, or is it just the compressed body? What is contained in the `data` that you passed to `zlib.decompress()`?

Comment: @mhawke .. My proxy will get the whole HTTP response, I want to decode the compressed body. When i am sending request of same page using get function i am getting normal HTML source code it, but when I am using proxy, it is showing the above thing.

Comment: What is in `data`? If `data` contains only gzipped data, `zlib.decompress(data, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)` should successfully decompress the data. Or you could use the `gzip` module as shown in my answer. But what are you passing in `data`?

Comment: @mhawke .. <pre>data</pre> contains the above shown information starting for url name, date and even that non printable characters

Comment: @mhawke ... another main doubt for me is why i am getting normal data when I am sending request from a program and why not in proxy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious way to do this is to extract the compressed data from the response and decompress it using `GzipFile().read()`. This method of splitting the response might be prone to failure, but here it goes:

```
from gzip import GzipFile
from StringIO import StringIO

http = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: nginx\r\nDate: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 12:02:25 GMT\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 115\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Encoding: gzip\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\r\n\r\n\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xa0\xda\xb9V\x02\xff\xab\xe6RPPJ\xaf\xca,(HMQ\xb2R()*M\xd5Q\x00\x89e\xa4&\xa6\xa4\x16\x15\x03\xc5\xaa\x81\\\xa0\x80G~q\t\x90\xa7\x94QRR\x90\x94\x99\xa7\x97_\x94\xae\x04\x94\xa9\x85(\xcfM-\xc9\xc8\x07\x99\xa0\xe4\xee\x1a\xa2\x04\x11\xcb/\xcaL\xcf\xcc\x03\x89\x19Z\x1a\xe9\x19\x9aY\xe8\x19\xea\x19*q\xd5r\x01\x00\r(\xafRu\x00\x00\x00'

body = http.split('\r\n\r\n', 1)[1]
print GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(body)).read()
```

**Output**

```
{
  "gzipped": true, 
  "headers": {
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }, 
  "method": "GET", 
  "origin": "192.168.1.1"
}
```

If you feel compelled to parse the full HTTP response message, then, as inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24729316/21945), here is a rather roundabout way to do it which involves constructing a `httplib.HTTPResponse` directly from the raw HTTP response, using that to create a `urllib3.response.HTTPResponse`, and then accessing the decompressed data:

```
import httplib
from cStringIO import StringIO
from urllib3.response import HTTPResponse

http = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: nginx\r\nDate: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 12:02:25 GMT\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 115\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Encoding: gzip\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\r\n\r\n\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\xa0\xda\xb9V\x02\xff\xab\xe6RPPJ\xaf\xca,(HMQ\xb2R()*M\xd5Q\x00\x89e\xa4&\xa6\xa4\x16\x15\x03\xc5\xaa\x81\\\xa0\x80G~q\t\x90\xa7\x94QRR\x90\x94\x99\xa7\x97_\x94\xae\x04\x94\xa9\x85(\xcfM-\xc9\xc8\x07\x99\xa0\xe4\xee\x1a\xa2\x04\x11\xcb/\xcaL\xcf\xcc\x03\x89\x19Z\x1a\xe9\x19\x9aY\xe8\x19\xea\x19*q\xd5r\x01\x00\r(\xafRu\x00\x00\x00'

class DummySocket(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = StringIO(data)
    def makefile(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._data

response = httplib.HTTPResponse(DummySocket(http))
response.begin()
response = HTTPResponse.from_httplib(response)
print(response.data)
```

**Output**

```
{
  "gzipped": true, 
  "headers": {
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }, 
  "method": "GET", 
  "origin": "192.168.1.1"
}
```

Comment: actually I am using proxy through which i can capture the source code of url in a browser. if I use request from from a python program I can get, but I want to capture automatically for all pages i am visiting in browser.

Comment: @krocks: I've updated my answer with 2 methods that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although `gzip` uses `zlib`, when `Content-Encoding` is set to `gzip`, there is an additional header before the compressed stream which is not properly interpreted by the `zlib.decompress` call.

Put your data in a `file-like` object and pass it through the `gzip` module. For example something like:

```
mydatafile = cStringIO.StringIO(data)
gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=mydatafile)
decdata = gzipper.read()
```

From my already old http library for Python 2.x

- https://github.com/mementum/httxlib/blob/master/httxlib/httxcompression.py